# Can anyone recommend a breadboard for the new Arduino 101?

Tags: arduino-uno, servo

I just got an Arduino 101 board. I was told that it's practically the same as the UNO. But have no experience using the UNO and I've only done super simple things on the 101 board without using a bread board.

What I want to do is have 2 servos connect to the board. I've only connected one servo without using a breadboard. I've looked on Instructables.com and other places that connect at least 2 to up most 12 servos. They all use different breadboards without specify if the brand, model, or if size even matters. I don't know how breadboards work and which holes I plug the wires into. Furthermore, I haven't found any videos on people working on the 101 board.

Next, I'm not sure if the servos will share the same volt port. There's only 3V and 5V on my Arduino 101 board. If they all need 5V, I'm not sure how to make both servos share. I don't know how they will share the same ground port as well. I know for sure, they will have their own analog port.

A list of recommendations would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: Although you will find tutorials which unwisely do so, you really should not power servos from any sort of Arduino.  Servos are nasty motor loads, which should have their own supply that is not an Arduino or the computer that is connected to.  They they need a common ground with the Arduino and signal from it.

Comment: I personally prefer the big breadboards that have two sets of terminals for power at the top. The tiny boards tend to get claustrophobic for me. Should have bought one big to begin with instead of the ones that are supercompact. Good for tiny (chinese) fingers though ... I just unravelled a mystery.

Comment: @user400344 however (probably) unintentional `Good for tiny (chinese) fingers though` sounds a little racist (depending on how you view it).

Comment: @junerockwell Sparkfun has a pretty neat tutorial on breadboards (https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-use-a-breadboard). But as Chris Stratton suggest, it's highly advised to separate power lines from control lines.

Comment: It's only a matter of personal preference. I am quite happy with the standard 830-point layout, but there are many larger and nicer models.

Answer (score 2):

A breadboard is nothing but a way to attach multiple wires to the same pins. There are many different kinds as can be seen [in these images](https://www.google.nl/search?q=breadboard&espv=2&biw=1777&bih=861&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUte3Jjf_NAhXG7hoKHVZwAjQQ_AUIBigB&dpr=0.9). There's no right or wrong when it comes to breadboards, as long as you have enough pins to prototype you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I agree to "A breadboard is nothing but a way to attach multiple wires to the same pins.", but just one recommendation for the breadboard. Don't buy the ones without the rails for voltage and ground, they are useful.